# How to use map to loop over json object in react js

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have a JSON object and I want to display it on my page but am having a problem with how to loop through the JSON object using the map function in React.

How can I display the data accessing the content of the object? Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance

My data

```
const product = {
  "items": {
    "page": "1",
    "real_total_results": 500,
    "total_results": 500,
    "page_size": 10,
    "pagecount": 50,
    "item": [

      {
        "title": "2022 Martin Men's Shoes Pigskin Autumn",
        "pic_url": "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01iURzli2Ka1udcUHnM_!!2212881679572-0-cib.jpg",
        "promotion_price": "83.00",
        "price": "83.00",
        "sales": 223,
        "turnover": "1万+",

      },
      {
        "title": "Single shoe summer",
        "pic_url": "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01eMAlUd1GfHlfmUnE1_!!2211426400649-0-cib.jpg",
        "promotion_price": "5.30",
        "price": "5.30",
        "sales": 381884,
        "turnover": "27万+",

      },
      {
        "title": "Men's shoes and women's shoes Beijing",
        "pic_url": "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01pshk1P27HAb7t9H5i_!!2208535077771-0-cib.jpg",
        "promotion_price": "5.00",
        "price": "5.00",
        "sales": 94815,
        "turnover": "7万+",

      },
      {
        "title": "2022 Running Shoes Sneakers",
        "pic_url": "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01KNh1N31Dwk4VGdCWB_!!2863830281-0-cib.jpg",
        "promotion_price": "82.00",
        "price": "82.00",
        "sales": 16573,
        "turnover": "4万+",
      },


    ],

  },

}
```

My code

```
<div className="row items">
            {product.items.map((values) => {
              return(   
                <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6" >
                  <span>Total: {values.total_results}</span>
                    values.item.map((val) =>{
                      return(
                        <div className="productImage">
                         <img style={{height:'100%', width: '100%'}}src={val.pic_url} alt="" />
                        </div>
                         <Link to='/' style={{textDecoration:'none', color:"#1a1a1a"}}>
                           <div className="cardDetail">
                            <div >
                              <p>{val.title}</p> 
                            </div>
                            <div>
                             <h6>¥ {val.price}</h6>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                             <h6>¥ {val.sales}</h6>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                  </Link>
                       )
                  })
                  
                  
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
```

I want to get the `page, total_results, page_size` and also get item array content like the `title, pic_url, prices` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `map` on `Object`, So you have to wrap the `product.items` into `Array` as you can see the below code also [here you can see the live example of your code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-water-n8resh?file=/src/App.js:0-2625)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const product = {
    items: {
      page: "1",
      real_total_results: 500,
      total_results: 500,
      page_size: 10,
      pagecount: 50,
      item: [
        {
          title: "2022 Martin Men's Shoes Pigskin Autumn",
          pic_url:
            "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01iURzli2Ka1udcUHnM_!!2212881679572-0-cib.jpg",
          promotion_price: "83.00",
          price: "83.00",
          sales: 223,
          turnover: "1万+"
        },
        {
          title: "Single shoe summer",
          pic_url:
            "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01eMAlUd1GfHlfmUnE1_!!2211426400649-0-cib.jpg",
          promotion_price: "5.30",
          price: "5.30",
          sales: 381884,
          turnover: "27万+"
        },
        {
          title: "Men's shoes and women's shoes Beijing",
          pic_url:
            "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01pshk1P27HAb7t9H5i_!!2208535077771-0-cib.jpg",
          promotion_price: "5.00",
          price: "5.00",
          sales: 94815,
          turnover: "7万+"
        },
        {
          title: "2022 Running Shoes Sneakers",
          pic_url:
            "https://cbu01.alicdn.com/img/ibank/O1CN01KNh1N31Dwk4VGdCWB_!!2863830281-0-cib.jpg",
          promotion_price: "82.00",
          price: "82.00",
          sales: 16573,
          turnover: "4万+"
        }
      ]
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Array(product.items).map((values) => {
        return (
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
            <span>Total: {values.total_results}</span>
            {values.item.map((val) => (
              <>
                <div className="productImage">
                  <img
                    style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                    src={val.pic_url}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <Link
                  to="/"
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#1a1a1a" }}
                >
                <div className="cardDetail">
                  <div>
                    <p>{val.title}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h6>¥ {val.price}</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h6>¥ {val.sales}</h6>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </Link>
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `product.items` is not an array, so you cannot use `map` on it.

You're also missing brackets in the 2nd `map`, and you need to add a wrapper element on JSX of the 2nd `map` as well, I use `React.Fragment` in this case.

It should be like below

```
<div className="row items">
  <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <span>Total: {product.items.total_results}</span>
    {product.items.item.map((val) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="productImage">
          <img
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            src={val.pic_url}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#1a1a1a" }}>
          <div className="cardDetail">
            <div>
              <p>{val.title}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h6>¥ {val.price}</h6>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h6>¥ {val.sales}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function is a method of the Array.prototype which means it won't work on an object